# SQL Retrieve Names Based on Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So I have three tables. CUSTOMER(**CustomerID**, LastName, FirstName), PURCHASE(**PurchaseID**, ItemName), and TRANSACTION(**CustomerID**, **PurchaseID**, Date).

The problem I am having is that I need to get the full name of the customers who specifically buy the both items "Paint" and "Books" but when I run my code nothing comes up. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.FirstName, CUSTOMER.LastName
FROM CUSTOMER, PURCHASE
WHERE PURCHASE.Item = 'Paint' AND PURCHASE.Item = 'Books'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.FirstName;
```

Please help, I am really new to this and would really like some help.

Comment: Please check by removing the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of problem is called `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  CUSTOMER.FirstName, CUSTOMER.LastName
FROM    CUSTOMER    
        INNER JOIN TRANSACTION
            ON CUSTOMER.CustomerID = TRANSACTION.CustomerID
        INNER JOIN PURCHASE
            ON TRANSACTION.PurchaseID = PURCHASE.PurchaseID
WHERE   PURCHASE.Item IN ('Paint', 'Books')  -- list all items here
GROUP   BY CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.FirstName
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHASE.Item) = 2 -- the total number of items searched
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

if there is a `UNIQUE` constraint that was enforced for every `ItemName` on each transaction, you can use `*`

```
SELECT  CUSTOMER.FirstName, CUSTOMER.LastName
FROM    CUSTOMER    
        INNER JOIN TRANSACTION
            ON CUSTOMER.CustomerID = TRANSACTION.CustomerID
        INNER JOIN PURCHASE
            ON TRANSACTION.PurchaseID = PURCHASE.PurchaseID
WHERE   PURCHASE.Item IN ('Paint', 'Books')
GROUP   BY CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.FirstName
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: great answer. Interestingly almost identical to the one I gave :) but yours is better. +1

Answer (score 1):

NO CONNECTION..

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER.FirstName, CUSTOMER.LastName
FROM CUSTOMER A 
JOIN TRANSACTION B
ON A.CUSTOMERID=B.CUSTOMERID
JOIN PURCHASE C
ON B.PURCHASEID=C.PURCHASEID AND C.ITEM='Paint'
JOIN PURCHASE D 
ON B.PURCHASEID=D.PURCHASEID AND D.C.Item = 'Books'
```

Comment: not flexible enough. think of this query when i want to search for 5 items. you need to add 3 more joins.

Comment: @JW 웃 yes,you are right. This is just my first response.You are all too fast..you know : )   .

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` tables. Try

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.FirstName, CUSTOMER.LastName
FROM   CUSTOMER 
       INNER JOIN TRANSACTION ON TRANSACTION.CustomerID=CUSTOMER.CustomerID 
       INNER JOIN PURCHASE ON PURCHASE.PurchaseID=TRANSACTION.PurchaseID
WHERE PURCHASE.Item = 'Paint' OR PURCHASE.Item = 'Books'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.FirstName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHASE.Item) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.FirstName, CUSTOMER.LastName
FROM CUSTOMER C, PURCHASE P, TRANSACTION T
WHERE
C.CUSTOMERID = T.CUSTOMERID AND T.PurchaseID = P.PurchaseID
AND P.Item IN ('Paint','Books')
```

This is pseudo code. Try it out by yourselves.